# dae to gltf pbr export not exporting textures not base64

Tags: collada, gltf

i have Dae, and separately textures that i'd like to include in the exproter.

I use collada2gltf exporter and do next steps

```
./COLLADA2GLTF-bin -i /Users/Andy/downloads/Ball_Dae/ball_v2.dae -o      /Users/Andy/downloads/Ball_Dae/Ball_Output --binary --metallicRoughnessTextures /Users/Andy/downloads/Ball_Dae/texture/
```

What i need is to create GLTF from dae and as pbr textures use textures from the /texture folder.

Not sure if i'm doing something right.

Comment: Did you intend for the glTF to have its own texture files?  Or embedded with base64 Data URIs?  Or all rolled into a binary `.glb` file?

Comment: i intend it to have it's own textures like if it will be fbx file with textures in other folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [COLLADA2GLTF docs](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/COLLADA2GLTF), if you want the textures to be separate from the rest of the glTF file, you must use the `--separate` option. It's possible that option is incompatible with `--binary`, which typically implies bundling everything into a single binary file. If the documented options aren't working, I'd suggest filing a bug on the COLLADA2GLTF repository.

Comment: Thanks, i suppose it's a bug. It's not exporting textures.